# ObjectDataSource could not find a non-generic method that has parameters when using update and delete

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am getting this error:

> "ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not find a non-generic
>   method 'UpdateEmployee' that has parameters: originalEmployeeId,
>   originalName, originalGender, originalCity, EmployeeId, Name, Gender,
>   City."

when I press the update button. But my delete button doesn;t have an issue. This is my code:
***WebForm1.aspx***

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataKeyNames="EmployeeId">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeId" HeaderText="EmployeeId" 
                SortExpression="EmployeeId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" 
                SortExpression="Gender" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetAllEmployee2S" TypeName="EditingData.Employee2" 
        UpdateMethod="UpdateEmployee" DeleteMethod="DeleteEmployee" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original{0}">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="originalEmployeeId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="originalName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="originalGender" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="originalCity" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="originalEmployeeId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="originalName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="originalGender" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="originalCity" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

</div>
</form>
```

***Employee2.cs***

```
public static List<Employee2> GetAllEmployee2S()
    {
        var dal = new Employee2Dal();
        return dal.GetAllEmployee2S();
    }
    public static void DeleteEmployee(int originalEmployeeId, string originalName, string originalGender, string originalCity)
    {
        var dal = new Employee2Dal();
        dal.DeleteEmployee(originalEmployeeId, originalName, originalGender, originalCity);
    }
    public static void UpdateEmployee(int originalEmployeeId, string originalName, string originalGender, string originalCity)
    {
        var dal = new Employee2Dal();
        dal.UpdateEmployee(originalEmployeeId, originalName, originalGender, originalCity);
    }
```

***Employee2Dal.cs***

```
public void DeleteEmployee(int originalEmployeeId, string originalName, string originalGender, string originalCity)
    {
        var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            const string deleteQuery = "Delete from Employee2 where EmployeeId=@OriginalEmployeeId and Name = @OriginalName and Gender = @OriginalGender and " +
                                       "City = @OriginalCity";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteQuery, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginalEmployeeId", originalEmployeeId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginalName", originalName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginalGender", originalGender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OriginalCity", originalCity);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    public void UpdateEmployee(int employeeId, string name, string gender, string city)
    {
        var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            const string updateQuery = "Update Employee2 set Name=@Name, Gender=@Gender, City=@City where EmployeeId=@EmployeeId";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", employeeId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for editing. I copied what you have proposed but stil this persists:  'could not find a non-generic method 'UpdateEmployee' that has parameters: EmployeeId, Name, Gender, City, originalEmployeeId, originalName, originalGender, originalCity.' Why is the objectdatasource is looking for 8 parameters when it only needs 4. It's like it is combining the delete parameters too.

Comment: When I delete ConfilictDetection, the update command works but the delete command does not work. Would it mean that I cannot use ConflictDetection together with UpdateCommand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code working, because `Delete` method does not require current values of parameters. So you have only old values parameters, which are formatted as `orignial{0}'. But with`Update`method you have both old and current values. Old values are also formatted with`original{0}` prefix, but current values are passed with unmodified names of GridView fields. So you have totally 8 parameters:

```
originalEmployeeId, originalName, originalGender, originalCity
employeeId, name, gender, city
```

You can simply add missing parameters to UpdateEmployee method. But I don't think you need original values here. And even more - you don't need any values for DeleteEmployee method except employee ID. So simply don't use original values (note that `ConflictDetection` should be equal to OverwriteChanges in order to turn off original values passing to Update method):

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    TypeName="EditingData.Employee2"
    SelectMethod="GetAllEmployee2S"  
    UpdateMethod="UpdateEmployee"
    DeleteMethod="DeleteEmployee" ConflictDetection="OverwriteChanges">       
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And let GridView pass parameters corresponding to field names

```
public static void DeleteEmployee(int employeeId)
{
    var dal = new Employee2Dal();
    dal.DeleteEmployee(employeeId); // modify dal method
}
public static void UpdateEmployee(int employeeId, string name, string gender, string city)
{
    var dal = new Employee2Dal();
    dal.UpdateEmployee(employeeId, name, gender, city);
}
```

Comment: I edited the UpdateEmployee itself. Please see the new UpdateEmployee. I still have the same issue.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 Please don't edit question. You can only add details describing your original problem. Renaming parameters in `UpdateEmployee` is solution too, but I think `orignalName`, `originalGender` etc are misleading names for update parameters.

Comment: Oh I understand it now Sergey. But, I cannot change the ConfictDetection because I need it in the delete cuncurrency.